# Magento transactional emails are not being sent & cron jobs are not working

Tags: magento2, cron

Magento is not sending any emails, no confirmation mails, no invoice mails, no shipment mails or anything. The server sends email by command line and the contact form works, but transactional mail is not being sent. How can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have SMTP set up for sending emails?

Comment: yes i have . i have problem sending mails